# Issue on staring tensorflow on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I opened Anaconda Navigator, Clicked on Environments, Clicked on Update Index, Selected Uninstalled from the drop down list, Searched for Tensorflow, Selected Keras and Selected Tensorflow, Clicked on Apply, and then I proceeded until the process finished successfully, I quit then. Afterwards, I opened Jupyter Notebook and typed the code "import tensorflow as tf"
However, I faced the following ERROR:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     61   try:
---> 62     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     63   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8976\3793406994.py in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     35 import typing as _typing
     36 
---> 37 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     38 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     39 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     34 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     35 
---> 36 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     37 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     38 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     75     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags)
     76 except ImportError:
---> 77   raise ImportError(
     78       f'{traceback.format_exc()}'
     79       f'\n\nFailed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.\n'

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common causes and solutions.
If you need help, create an issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues and include the entire stack trace above this error message.
```

Comment: did you select the right environment?

Comment: what python vesion are you runing, in your environment?

Comment: which version of windows are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Please install the **Jupyter** notebook in the same way you installed `Tensorflow` and `Keras` libraries within that environment of Anaconda Navigator.

and you will find that `TensorFlow` and `keras` are accessible through Jupyter notebook.